# UITableViewController: How can I subclass the its toolbar for drawing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with the standard toolbar. I would like to alter the styling of this toolbar.

Is it possible to subclass the UITableView.toolbar and override drawRect?

Comment: I don't believe UIViewController or it's subclasses takes a class for their toolbar.  You could either swizzle it's `drawRect:`, or go with UIAppearance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `UIAppearance`:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It seems it doesnt do anything if you override `drawRect:`, instead you need to override `drawLayer:inContext:`

http://atastypixel.com/blog/making-uitoolbar-and-uinavigationbars-background-totally-transparent/